# Transform timestamp from long to a presto suitable format

Tags: json, apache-kafka, presto

I'm trying to access kafka topic using presto, one of the fields in my kafka message is a timestamp. The timestamp is stored as a long and I want it be recognised by presto as a timestamp.

What dataformat should I use for presto to recognise it as a timestamp in the `default.test.json` file while structuring the message data?

```
            ....
            {
                "name": "timestamp",
                "mapping": "time",
                "type": "TIMESTAMP",
                "dataFormat": "?????"
            }
            ....
```

Comment: According to https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/kafka.html#json-decoder you can use any of `custom-date-time, iso8601, rfc2822, milliseconds-since-epoch, seconds-since-epoch` here. Did you try? Did it work for you?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I tried `iso8601, rfc2822, milliseconds-since-epoch, seconds-since-epoch`, the timestamp is still not being recognised, so all the values are NULL in the table. Are there any other options I could try?